# Symbols missing in time profiler xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, symbols

Upon discovering certain performance issues in an application of mine, I decided to start working with instruments. Or more specifically the time profiler.

However when I run this magnificent piece of technology, I notice that no symbols are being loaded for my app. Despite having looked everywhere and tried almost every setting and piece of advice I could find on the internet, I still remain symbol-less.

So as a final resort I decided to post here in the hope that somebody could point me in the right direction.

What I've tried so far:

(cleaned before every change that I made)

- profiling in debug mode
- setting all symbol related settings in the app configuration to include debug symbols, both in release and debug
- "resymbolicating" (this button is absent in my instruments version, it's merely called "Symbols...") when clicking "locate" and selecting my app's dYSM file, I get "the specified path didn't locate a dYSM for any of the libraries"

Could this be an issue related to the beta version of xcode that I'm using? I'm using xcode 6 Version 6.0 (6A215l) and instruments Version 6.0 (56107.10.7.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the project and restarting Instruments fixed this for me.
Xcode 6 GM Version 6.0 (6A313) and Instruments Version 6.0 (56156)